# Core Data Fatal-Exception: This NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores (unknown). It cannot perform a save operation

Tags: ios, core-data, fatal-error

I have an app that currently makes use of a custom Cocoa Touch Framework called MyFramework. Within it I have a dependency on Core Data, which I use to cache data in a SQLite store.

During testing everything worked as expected, but now that I've shared the app to a growing number of users, I get the following fatal exception:

```
Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x1848651b8 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x18329c55c objc_exception_throw
2  CoreData                       0x186c49260 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator _coordinator_you_never_successfully_opened_the_database_corrupted:]
3  CoreData                       0x186c494b8 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator _introspectLastErrorAndThrow]
4  CoreData                       0x186c49840 __65-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:]_block_invoke
5  CoreData                       0x186c42bf0 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator _routeHeavyweightBlock:]
6  CoreData                       0x186b67f20 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:]
7  CoreData                       0x186b67f4c -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:]
8  CoreData                       0x186b895ac -[NSManagedObjectContext save:]
9  MyFramework                    0x1016608a4 (Missing)
10 CoreData                       0x186c0de98 developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x1836ee1bc _dispatch_client_callout
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x1836fc3dc _dispatch_queue_serial_drain
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x1836f19a4 _dispatch_queue_invoke
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x1836fe34c _dispatch_root_queue_drain
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x1836fe0ac _dispatch_worker_thread3
16 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1838f72a0 _pthread_wqthread
17 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1838f6d8c start_wqthread
```

I can tell that the problem is with the NSPersistentStoreCoordinator, and that the database is some how corrupted. However, I have searched the web and was only able to find information regarding other NSPersistentStoreCoordinator issues, nothing on this.

Has anyone faced this problem, and even if you haven't, does anyone know how to fix, or prevent it?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

I have seen the question mentioned by @LoVo in the comments, however I'm not sure the "device_locked" error correlates to that of "database_corrupted".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Crash on iOS9 with -\[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator \_coordinator\_you\_never\_successfully\_opened\_the\_database\_device\_locked:\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33251528/crash-on-ios9-with-nspersistentstorecoordinator-coordinator-you-never-success)

Comment: @B.N did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @MattyG I ended up following the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33262064/6046916) on the link shared by LoVo. Although it is not the exact same issue, that approach seems to mitigate the issue.