# How to handle a CoreData crash in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, crash

I need to handle a core data crash. My code got crashed on the managedObjectContext.save().
But catch block did not catch any exception. To avoid the crash how can I write my Catch block better Here is my code.

```
do {
      try managedObjectContext.save()              
   } 
catch let error as NSError {
      Print.print("Error saving data store: \(error)")
     }
```

Comment: It may be a memory issue. How much data you are saving?

Comment: What is the crash? post here...

Comment: How to predict crash with this code. add crash log here

Comment: print("Error saving data store: \(error)") you have to use print statement like this .Can you change print statement and run it again .

Comment: 0   CoreFoundation                 0x191c76fe0 __exceptionPreprocess + 124 (NSException.m:165)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                0x1906d8538 objc_exception_throw + 56 (objc-exception.mm:521)
2   CoreData                       0x19402d828 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator _coordinator_you_never_successfully_opened_the_database_disk_full:] + 56 (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator.m:2616)
3   CoreData                       0x19402d930 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator _introspectLastErrorAndThrow] + 208 (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator.m:2646)

Comment: Can you please provide more code of core data that you have done

Answer (score 3):

This is the sample for saving data using CoreData .This may helps you .

```
 let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        if let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Employees", in: context){
           let myItem = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: context)
            myItem.setValue(nameTF.text, forKey: "names")
            myItem.setValue(15655, forKey: "mobileNo")

            do {
                try context.save()

            }catch let nserror as NSError{
                print("ERROR: Coredata error \(nserror)")
            }

        }
```

Comment: My error is not caught in the catch block. How can I write multiple catches for the exception?

Comment: Error you will get in catch block no need to write multiple catch blocks.Make sure you are getting error in code data.

Answer (score 1):

This really looks like you messed up with your initialization of context, persistent store and its coordinator. You would do best looking into that. There are similar posts already on SO like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33251528/crash-on-ios9-with-nspersistentstorecoordinator-coordinator-you-never-success).

More importantly you will not intercept such exception with `try-catch` in Swift. Realistically the Swift `try-catch` does not have anything to do with exceptions but is a high level API for you to intercept reported errors. In your case you just intercept the error that may be reported when saving your data into database. But the error came from a bit deeper as it seems.

To go a step further the whole core data is still completely in objectiveC which has completely different system for throwing exceptions and although those exceptions MAY be intercepted with objectiveC `try-catch` the same exception will not be intercepted by the one from Swift. What this system did is only replaced entering of pointer to error into method: `.save(&error)` which was used in objectiveC. And your catch block will trigger only when this error is non-null.